# Kotlin: Why can you call awaitAll on a list of promises?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Lets see this code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val deferreds: List<Deferred<Int>> = (1..3).map {
        async {
            delay(50L * it)
            it
        }
    }
    val sum = awaitAll(deferreds[0], deferreds[1], deferreds[2]).sum()
    println("$sum")
}
```

Above we call `awaitAll` with a varargs. This is how the [source code for `awaitAll`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Await.kt#L23) looks:

```
public suspend fun <T> awaitAll(vararg deferreds: Deferred<T>): List<T> =
    if (deferreds.isEmpty()) emptyList() else AwaitAll(deferreds).await()
```

But apparently we can also call `awaitAll` on the list of promises:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val deferreds: List<Deferred<Int>> = (1..3).map {
        async {
            delay(50L * it)
            it
        }
    }
    val sum2 = deferreds.awaitAll().sum()
    println("$sum2")
}
```

How is this possible if `awaitAll` is not an extension function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [`kotlinx.coroutines.awaitAll`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Await.kt#L38) it looks like the `awaitAll` method is both a global function and an extension method of the `Collection<Deferred<T>>` template class.

Either should work just as well and do basically the same thing, it's up to you to use the one which you prefer and which fits your standard the best!

Comment: I can't believe that method has been in front of my eyes the entire time! I was too focused on the other one.